# Not all lines display in UITableViewController tableview object

Tags: ios, uitableview, gridlines

I have this happening in a couple of different tableview objects. Not all my gridlines show up - in example here, just between 'ticks' and 'Rattle Snakes' (Oh yes, that is a compound word! I better edit~)

I tried putting the same thumbnail image into this one, thinking I'd see something obvious.... But I don't.

[image: TableView object doesn't show all gridlines]

Comment: probably something isn't right with the height of the cell

Comment: Your simulator window isn't scaled to 100%.

Comment: You are so right Maddy. I will go and look at the tags for the duplicate and figure out why I didn't find it before I asked. Thank you.